# how to add outside data to table data in material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I want to add this row to material-table as default data. In my code I already have data={tableData} in material-table as data being added to the table by a form.
below is the row I want to add

```
     <Row>
                <Col lg={6}>
                <TextField
                    label='Borrower/Applicant Name'
                    variant='standard'
                    color='warning'
                    name='borrower_Applicant'
                    className='mb-3'
                    onChange={(e) => setBorrower_Applicant(e.target.value)}
                    value={borrower_Applicant}
                    disabled={isView || borrower_Applicant?.length > 0}
                />
                {error && error?.borrower_Applicant && ( <span style={{color: "#da251e", width: "100%", textAlign: "start", }}>
                    {error.borrower_Applicant}
                    </span>
                )}
                </Col>
                <Col lg={6}>
                <TextField
                    label='lenders'
                    variant='standard'
                    color='warning'
                    name='lenders'
                    className='mb-3'
                    onChange={(e) => setLenders(e.target.value)}
                    value={lenders}
                    disabled={isView || borrower_Applicant?.length > 0}
                />
                {error && error?.lenders && (<span style={{ color: "#da251e", width: "100%", textAlign: "start"}}>{error.lenders}</span> )}
                </Col>
            </Row>
```

> **Below is my material table. i want to find a way to insert the row above to show in the table. **

```
<MaterialTable
            title=""
            columns={[
                { title: 'Name', field: 'name.label' },
                { title: 'Label', field: 'type.label' },
            ]}
            data={tableData}
            actions={isView ? [{
                icon: 'preview',
                tooltip: 'View Product',
                onClick: (event, rowData) => { setShowEditModal(!showEditModal); setRowEditData(rowData); setView(isView) }
            }] : [
                {
                    icon: 'edit',
                    tooltip: 'Edit Product',
                    onClick: (event, rowData) => { setRowEditData(rowData); setShowEditModal(!showEditModal); console.log('rowData ==', rowData) }
                },
                {
                    icon: 'preview',
                    tooltip: 'View Product',
                    onClick: (event, rowData) => { setShowEditModal(!showEditModal); setRowEditData(rowData) }
                }
            ]}
            options={{
                filtering: true,
                actionsColumnIndex: -1,
                sorting: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                search: false,
                emptyRowsWhenPaging: false,
            }}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

how i solved this was by going through material table custom rendering in their  [material table docs](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/custom-column-rendering). there is a render property in material-table lets you to override a render of any column.

> In my case, I wanted to render a default table that couldn't be editable. here's how I went about it

```
<MaterialTable
                title=""
                columns={[
                     { title: 'Name', field: 'name.label' },
                    { title: 'Label', field: 'type.label' },
                    { title: 'Borrower/Applicant', render: rowData =>  
                    <Row>
                        <Col lg={12} className="mb-4">
                            <TextField
                                label='Borrower/Applicant Name'
                                variant='standard'
                                color='warning'
                                name='borrower_Applicant'
                                
                                // onChange={(e) => setBorrower_Applicant(e.target.value)}
                                value={getBorrower}
                                disabled={true}
                            />
                        </Col>
                     </Row>},
                    { title: 'Lender', render: rowData =>  
                    <Row>
                       <Col lg={12} className="mb-4">
                            <TextField
                                label='Lenders'
                                variant='standard'
                                color='warning'
                                name='lenders'
                                
                                // onChange={(e) => setLenders(e.target.value)}
                                value={getLender}
                                disabled={true}
                            />
                        </Col>
                     </Row>},
                   
                    
                ]}
                data={tableData}

                actions={isView ? [{
                    icon: 'preview',
                    tooltip: 'View Product',
                    onClick: (event, rowData) => { setShowEditModal(!showEditModal); setRowEditData(rowData); setView(isView) }
                }] : [
                    {
                        icon: 'edit',
                        tooltip: 'Edit Product',
                        onClick: (event, rowData) => { setRowEditData(rowData); setShowEditModal(!showEditModal); console.log('rowData ==', rowData) }
                    },
                    {
                        icon: 'preview',
                        tooltip: 'View Product',
                        onClick: (event, rowData) => { setShowEditModal(!showEditModal); setRowEditData(rowData) }
                    }
                ]}
                options={{
                    filtering: true,
                    actionsColumnIndex: -1,
                    sorting: true,
                    pageSize: 10,
                    search: false,
                    emptyRowsWhenPaging: false,
                }}
            />
```